# Adding cookies to jquery toggle video-bg switcher

Tags: jquery, cookies, html5-video, toggle

Don't know about cookies much. I just want to my **Play\Pause button to remember it's state**, nothing more. Here is the code, please help. **Thank you**

```
$('.video-control').on('click', function () {
    $(this).toggleClass('video-control_active');
    var currentVideo = document.querySelector('.play');
    if (currentVideo.paused) {
        currentVideo.play();
    } else {
        currentVideo.pause()
    }
})
```

Comment: you are not using cookies at all in this snippet. Please read https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1458724/how-do-i-set-unset-a-cookie-with-jquery to get and idea of what you need to save a state as cookie.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, I returned to the case and read a bit. This worked for me:

```
    if(localStorage.paused !== 'true') playlist();
    else {
        videos[currPlayVideo].classList.add('play');
        videos[currPlayVideo].onended = function () {
            playNextVideo();
        };
        $('.video-control').remove('video-control_active');
    };
    $('.video-control').on('click', function () {
        var currentVideo = document.querySelector('.play');
        $(this).toggleClass('video-control_active');
        if (currentVideo.paused) {
            currentVideo.play();
            localStorage.paused = 'false'
        } else {
            currentVideo.pause();
            localStorage.paused = 'true'
        }
    });
```

and for the Play|pause button to remeber it's state the following:

```
if (localStorage.getItem("paused") == "true") {
  getFav = localStorage.paused;
  $(".video-control").addClass('video-control_active');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Read cookie when *video-playing* is the name.

```
var youCookie = $.cookie('video-playing');
```

Create or/and update cookie

```
$.cookie('video-playing', "true");
$.cookie('video-playing', "false");
```